# How can I autologin to desktop with systemd?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, systemd

How can I configure systemd to automatically log me in to my desktop environment, preferably without using a login manager? I'm using Arch Linux.

Comment: Which login manager are you using? Some (GDM, KDM, iirc, maybe more) already support autologin so you would only need to enable the service for them.

Comment: I'm currently using SLiM and it can be configured to autologin, but without a display manager the boot process would be faster and more flickerless :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is described in the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Getty#Automatic_login_to_virtual_console):

> Create a new service file similar to `getty@.service` by copying it to `/etc/systemd/system/`
>
> ```
> cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service
> ```

This basically copies the already existing `getty@.service` to a new file `autologin@.service` which can be freely modified. It is copied to `/etc/systemd/system` because that's where site-specific unit files are stored. `/usr/lib/systemd/system` contains unit files provided by packages so you shouldn't change anything in there.

You will then have to symlink that `autologin@.service` to the getty service for the tty on which you want to autologin, for examply for tty1:

```
ln -s /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
```

Up to now, this is still the same as the usual `getty@.service` file, but the most important part is to modify the `autologin@.service` to actually log you in automatically.
To do that, you only need to change the `ExecStart` line to read

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -a USERNAME %I 38400
```

The difference between the `ExecStart` line in `getty@.service` and `autologin@.service` is only the `-a USERNAME` which tells agetty to log the user with the username USERNAME in automatically.

Now you only have to tell systemd to reload its daemon files and start the service:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start getty@tty1.service
```

(I'm not sure if the service will start properly if you're already logged in on tty1, the safest way is probably to just reboot instead of starting the service).

If you then want to automatically start X, insert the following snippet into your `~/.bash_profile` (taken from [the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xinit#Autostart_X_at_login) again):

```
if [[ -z $DISPLAY ]] && [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]]; then
    exec startx
fi
```

You will have to modify your `~/.xinitrc` to start your desktop environment, how to do that depends on the DE and is probably described in the ArchWiki as well.

Comment: What is the agetty arg %I?

Comment: I get the error `File exists` when I do the symlink

Comment: use `ln -sf /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service` to overwrite it.

Answer (score 12):

IMO, the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Getty#Automatic_login_to_virtual_console) currently recommends a much simpler solution:

Either run the helper (`systemctl edit getty@tty1`) or do what I did manually:

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/
touch /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
```

The text you want to enter (by either method) is (*be sure to change **username** appropriately*):

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/agetty --autologin username --noclear %I $TERM
```

**NOTE**: The empty line is important! The empty line will first clear the ExecStart entry, while the next line will introduce a new exec command.

Now, restart (`shutdown -r 0`) and something to the effect of `... login: username (automatic login)` will happen where it previously blocked waiting for username/password input

---

Once rebooted, and auto-logged in, if you're like me and want to SSH into this system now, you probably need to run:

```
systemctl enable sshd.service
```

Which will create the symlink (e.g. `ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service' '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service'`)

Comment: The arch wiki also mentions that if you still want it to require a password, but you don't want to type your username, replace `--autologin username` with `--skip-login --login-options username`

Comment: Thanks, this is the best method.

Comment: On Fedora it's `/usr/sbin/agetty` (not `/usr/bin/agetty`)

Answer (score 9):

Directly modify the file `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service` (which is a symlink to `/lib/systemd/system/getty@service`):

Append `-a/--autologin USERNAME` to the line:

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM
```

Hence:

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -a USERNAME %I $TERM
```

You might also remove `-o '-p -- \\u'` (as present on the current Arch installation) as this would start the login for `USERNAME` but still asks for the password.

After rebooting, you will be logged in automatically.

**P.s.** Change the filename `getty@tty1.service` to the `tty` you want to log into.

Comment: Note for clarity: if it's a symlink, replace the symlink with a new file, and edit that new file.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `getty` (get tty) command which allows you to auto login the specified user automatically, the argument of the `getty` can be either `--autologin` or `-a`, I am running Linux Debian Ubuntu so I don't know if this command is available in other distros.

```
getty -a <user>
```